# "while" with "find" in bash

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to run this script but it doesn't work.

I want to read each line from "libro.csv" (each line is the name of each audio) then assign this value to $audio. Finally, I want search this audio file in a directory and cp it to a new location

It can read each line from the CSV file, and assign the value for the variable. But when it tries to execute the FIND command, doesn't work.

The file `libro.csv` contains file names. For example:

```
audio
1532365967
1532382681
1538062773
```

http://www.filedropper.com/libro

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read audio
do
    echo "$audio"
    find /Audios/busqueda/ -name "*$audio*" | xargs -i cp {} /Audios/busqueda/copia
done < libro.csv
```

I run the script like this:

```
[root@linux busqueda]# ./buscar.sh audio 1532365967 1532382681 1538062773
```

I get no error messages, but the files aren't copied.

Comment: Do your file names actually have the `-` or was that just to make a list in your question? Also, when you say it doesn't work, that doesn't tell us anything. How does it fail? Is there an error message? Does it just not do what you expect?Does it do something else? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Is `[![libro.csv][1]][1]` an actual filename, or would you need to extract the `libro.csv` filename from it?

Comment: [![libro.csv][1]][1] is an actual filename, this file contains the name of each audio.

Comment: I am nearly confused... you want to read through the file, see if a line matches a filename, and if it does, cp it to a new location? If so, did you reference [this post from stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566591/bash-loop-over-files-listed-in-a-text-file-and-move-them)?

Comment: I want to read each line from "libro.csv" (each line is the name of each audio) then assign this value to $audio. Finally, I want search this audio file in a directory and cp it to a new location.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an example of the file. You seem to have posted a link to some sort of spreadhseet. Is this a text file? If yes, then please copy/paste a few lines from the file into your question. And please answer my original comment: how does it not work? What errors do you get?

Comment: Hi @terdon, Excuse me, I've already edited my post. 
This is the result of my script:

[root@linux busqueda]# ./buscar.sh
audio
1532365967
1532382681
1538062773

There isn't any error, but it doesn't find neither copy the files.

Comment: Why are you running the script like that? Your script is to read from the file on the command line. (e.g. ./buscar.sh libro.csv). I again state that the link I provided has a solution to this problem.

Comment: @AlexM but why are you passing arguments? Your script doesn't read them. And what are the target file names? If you get no error message, that probably means the `find` command had no results. This will be easier to debug if you could come into [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86927/discussion-on-question-by-alex-m-while-with-find-in-bash) for a few minutes. Ping me (`@terdon`) if you do.

Comment: @number9 no, the script in the OP doesn't take _any_ arguments. The name of the input file is also hard coded, so `./buscar.sh libro.csv` wouldn't make sense either.

Comment: @terdon Ah, yes, I was reading back my own test I did from the post I linked to. Ops.

Comment: I see the issue, the problem is that this: find /Audios/busqueda/ -name "*$audio*" works fine on the cli, but not in a script. It is the way the shell is expanding the "*$audio*" statement. You can mostly fix this by doing find ./whatever "*$audio*" -type f but it will also try to search for your carriage returns from the IFS read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that your file was created in Windows and therefore has Windows style line endings (`\r\n`) instead of the default UNIX:

```
$ head -n1 libro.csv | od -c
0000000   a   u   d   i   o  \r  \n
0000007
```

Therefore, when you run your script, the variable `$audio` isn't `1532365967` but `1532365967\r`, the `\r` is part of the variable's value. Since you have no files with `\r` in their names, the `find` command returns nothing and therefore nothing is copied.

You also don't need `xargs` here, you can do the whole thing with `find`. Here's a working version of what you need to do:

```
sed 's/\r//g' libro.csv | while IFS= read -r audio; do
    find /Audios/busqueda/ -name "*$audio*" -exec mv {} /Audios/busqueda/copia \;
done
```

Note that that will also look for the header, `audio` since that's part of the file. To avoid that, do:

```
tail -n +2 libro.csv | sed 's/\r//g' | while IFS= read -r audio; do
    find /Audios/busqueda/ -name "*$audio*" -exec mv {} /Audios/busqueda/copia \;
done
```

Comment: thanks!
Your answer was perfect. It works fine.